# How to maximize the number of variables with value at least 0?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, modeling, logical-constraints

Given a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$, I would like to find a vector $x$ satisfying the set of linear constraints $A x \leq b$, and subject to that, contains as many variables as possible with nonnegative value.

An obvious solution is to loop over all subsets of variables. For every subset $S$, check if the following set of constraints is feasible:

\begin{align}
A x &\leq b;
\\
x_i &\geq 0 && \forall i\in S
\end{align}

Then, return the solution for the largest set $S$ for which the constraints are feasible.
But this solution takes time exponential in the number of variables.

Is there a polynomial-time solution?

Comment: It seems that it is an LP problem. LP is always solvable in polynomial time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $L_i$ be a constant lower bound on $x_i$. Introduce binary variables $y_i$ and maximize $\sum_i y_i$ subject to $Ax\le b$ and $L_i (1-y_i)\le x_i$ for all $i$. The new constraints enforce the logical implications $y_i=1 \implies x_i\ge 0$, which you could alternatively enforce via indicator constraints.

---

For the NP-hardness, here's a reduction from independent set.  Explicitly, you are given graph $G=(N,E)$ and positive integer $k$.  Let binary decision variable $z_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.  You want to determine whether there is a solution to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in N} z_i &\ge k \\
z_i + z_j &\le 1 &&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$} \\
z_i &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i \in N$} 
\end{align}
Now take $x_i = z_i-1$ (so that $x_i \ge 0$ corresponds to $z_i = 1$) and rewrite the constraints as
\begin{align}
-\sum_{i\in N} x_i &\le |N|-k \\
x_i + x_j &\le -1 &&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$} \\
-x_i &\le 1 &&\text{for $i \in N$} \\
x_i &\le 0 &&\text{for $i \in N$} 
\end{align}
This is in the form of your original problem, which is therefore at least as hard as independent set.

Comment: I believe it should be mentioned that this cannot be solved in polynomial time (since OP asked).

Comment: Since the new variables $y_i$ are binary, solving the new program requires, in the worst case, to check all $2^n$ possible combinations of their values, which is similar to the solution I described (checking all $2^n$ possible subsets of variables $x_i$). Is there a polynomial-time solution?

Comment: I suspect that there is no polynomial-time algorithm, but the formulation I suggested should in practice perform much better than brute force.